# HTML/Javascript - can't change style.display to none

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying for the first time to work with forms in HTML. But sadly, I have a problem that I'm unable to solve. I want to show specific form-rows at a specifically selected option. I can change the style to `display: block`, but a few form-rows are permanently displayed and I can change it to `display: none` to hide it.

**Here a Video preview of the problem:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmEKfAOR7A8

Or test it live here: https://bl4cklist.de/contact

My JS code for the display Thing:

```js
function yesnoCheck() {

  // Allgemeine Fragen

  if (document.getElementById("yesCheck").selected) {
    document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes2").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes3").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes4").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes5").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("formstart").scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes3").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes4").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes5").style.display = "none";
  }

  // User-Report

  if (document.getElementById("yesCheck1").selected) {
    document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes3").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes4").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes5").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes6").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes7").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes8").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes9").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes10").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes11").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("formstart").scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ifYes6").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes7").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes8").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes9").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes10").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes11").style.display = "none";
  }

  // No Check

  if (document.getElementById("noCheck").selected) {
    document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes3").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes4").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes5").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes2").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes3").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes4").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes5").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col">
    <label class="mb-1 text-6"><img class="rounded" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/2222/2222355.png" height="30" width="30"> - Wie können wir dir helfen?</label>
    <div class="custom-select-1">

      <!-- Here is the JavaScript function started -->

      <select onchange="yesnoCheck(this);" class="form-control h-auto" name="city" required>
        <option id="noCheck" value="">Thema auswählen..</option>
        <option id="yesCheck" value="Allgemeine-Frage"> - Allgemeine Frage zu Bl4cklist</option>
        <option id="yesCheck1" value="User-Report"> - Server-Mitglied verstößt gegen Regeln</option>
        <option id="yesCheck2" value="Entsperrungs-Antrag"> - Mein Account wurde vom Server gesperrt</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Allgemeine-Frage -->

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6" id="ifYes" style="display: none;text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Mein Name</label>
    <div class="position-relative">
      <i class="far fa-user-circle text-color-primary text-3 position-absolute left-10 top-50pct transform3dy-n50"></i>
      <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Max Mustermann" maxlength="100" class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="name" required style="padding:35px;">
      <div class="help-tip" style="top:-30px;left:97px;">
        <p>Trage ihn ein, damit wir dich persönlich ansprechen können.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6" id="ifYes1" style="display: none;text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Meine E-Mail Adresse</label>
    <div class="position-relative">
      <i class="far fa-paper-plane text-color-primary text-3 position-absolute left-10 top-50pct transform3dy-n50"></i>
      <input type="email" value="" placeholder="bl4cklistde@gmail.com" maxlength="100" class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="email" required style="padding:35px;">
      <div class="help-tip" style="top:-30px;left:175px;">
        <p>Trage hier deine E-Mail ein, damit wir dir antworten können.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6" id="ifYes2" style="display: none;text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Überschrift</label>
    <div class="position-relative">
      <i class="far fa-edit text-color-primary text-3 position-absolute left-10 top-50pct transform3dy-n50"></i>
      <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Frage zu eurem Support-Bot" maxlength="50" class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="subject" required style="padding:35px;">
      <div class="help-tip" style="top:-30px;left:93px;">
        <p>Erkläre hier kurzgefasst worum es bei deinem Anliegen geht.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6" id="ifYes3" style="display: none;text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Thema deiner Frage</label>
    <div class="custom-select-1">
      <select class="form-control text-3 h-auto" name="city" maxlength="100" required>
        <option value="">Thema auswählen..</option>
        <option value="Webseite">Unsere Webseite</option>
        <option value="Discord-Bots">Unsere Discord-Bots</option>
        <option value="Discord-Server">Unser Discord-Server</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row" id="ifYes4" style="display: none;">
  <div class="form-group col">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Erkläre nun dein Anliegen..</label>
    <div class="position-relative">
      <i class="far fa-comment-dots text-color-primary text-3 position-absolute left-10 top-50pct transform3dy-n50"></i>
      <textarea maxlength="2000" rows="5" placeholder="Verfasse eine Nachricht.." class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="message" required style="padding:35px;"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row" id="ifYes5" style="display: none;">
  <div class="form-group col">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="finish1" value="Meine Frage abschicken" class="btn btn-primary btn-modern" data-loading-text="Laden..">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- User-Report -->

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col" id="ifYes6" style="display: none;text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Mein Discord-Name
                                    <div class="help-tip" style="left:105px;"><p>Trage ihn ein, damit wir dich persönlich ansprechen können.</p></div>
                                </label>
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Max Mustermann" maxlength="100" class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="name" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col" id="ifYes7" style="display: none;text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Meine E-Mail Adresse
                                    <div class="help-tip" style="left:180px;"><p>Trage hier deine E-Mail ein, damit wir dir antworten können.</p></div>
                                </label>
    <input type="email" value="" placeholder="bl4cklistde@gmail.com" maxlength="100" class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="email" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col" id="ifYes8" style="display: none;text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Überschrift
                                    <div class="help-tip" style="left:105px;"><p>Erkläre hier kurzgefasst worum es bei deinem Anliegen geht.</p></div>
                                </label>
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Frage zu eurem Support-Bot" maxlength="50" class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="subject" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col" id="ifYes9" style="display: none;text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Thema deiner Frage</label>
    <div class="custom-select-1">
      <select class="form-control h-auto" name="city" maxlength="100" required>
        <option value="">Thema auswählen..</option>
        <option value="Webseite">Unsere Webseite</option>
        <option value="Discord-Bots">Unsere Discord-Bots</option>
        <option value="Discord-Server">Unser Discord-Server</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row" id="ifYes10" style="display: none;">
  <div class="form-group col">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Erkläre nun dein Anliegen..</label>
    <textarea maxlength="2000" rows="5" class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="message" required></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row" id="ifYes11" style="display: none;">
  <div class="form-group col">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="finish1" value="Meine Frage abschicken" class="btn btn-primary btn-modern" data-loading-text="Laden..">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I look at the code "DRY" comes to my mind: "dont repeat yourself" ...

Comment: Hi! Please **reduce** the code in the question to a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using the Stack Snippet Barmar already started for you. [More about Stack Snippets here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: Yep, maybe the OP can use `for` loops

Comment: Separately, I suggest using CSS classes, not manipulating the style of individual elements. The descendant selector is a powerful thing.

Comment: When I run your code it hides and shows different divs after selecting from the dropdown. I think the problem is with your `if/then` logic. You don't need 3 `if/then`, it should be `if/else if/else if/else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not touch your HTML (apart from removing the individual `display:none` style attributes) but shortened your script considerably. The information you should use to trigger actions is the `value` of your select element - *not* their `id`. These values can be "Allgemeine-Frage", User-Report,"" or "Entsperrungs-Antrag". For the last case I made up some elements to show as the information was missing in your snippet.

Now: depending on which selection was made I use a different CSS-selector for the `document.querySelectorAll()` call which will then make some of the further input fields visible again. As you can see: fewer repetitions and a clearer logic are the result.

```js
function yesnoCheck(sel) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".show").forEach(d=>d.classList.remove("show"));
  document.getElementById("formstart").scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth'});
  document.querySelectorAll(  
{ "Allgemeine-Frage"   :"#ifYes,#ifYes1,#ifYes2,#ifYes3,#ifYes4,#ifYes5",
  "User-Report"        :"#ifYes6,#ifYes7,#ifYes8,#ifYes9,#ifYes10,#ifYes11",
  "Entsperrungs-Antrag":"#ifYes,#ifYes1" }[sel.value]
  ).forEach(d=>d.classList.add("show"));
}
```

```css
.show { display:block !important }
div[id^=ifYes] { display:none }
```

```html
<p id="formstart" class="text-5 appear-animation" data-appear-animation="fadeInRightShorter" data-appear-animation-delay="700">Fülle das untere Formular aus, um das Team zu kontaktieren.<br />Wir werden dir so schnell es geht professionell weiterhelfen.</p>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col">
    <label class="mb-1 text-6"><img class="rounded" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/2222/2222355.png" height="30" width="30"> - Wie können wir dir helfen?</label>
    <div class="custom-select-1">

      <!-- Here is the JavaScript function started -->

      <select onchange="yesnoCheck(this);" class="form-control h-auto" name="city" required>
        <option id="noCheck" value="">Thema auswählen..</option>
        <option id="yesCheck" value="Allgemeine-Frage"> - Allgemeine Frage zu Bl4cklist</option>
        <option id="yesCheck1" value="User-Report"> - Server-Mitglied verstößt gegen Regeln</option>
        <option id="yesCheck2" value="Entsperrungs-Antrag"> - Mein Account wurde vom Server gesperrt</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Allgemeine-Frage -->

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6" id="ifYes" style="text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Mein Name</label>
    <div class="position-relative">
      <i class="far fa-user-circle text-color-primary text-3 position-absolute left-10 top-50pct transform3dy-n50"></i>
      <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Max Mustermann" maxlength="100" class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="name" required style="padding:35px;">
      <div class="help-tip" style="top:-30px;left:97px;">
        <p>Trage ihn ein, damit wir dich persönlich ansprechen können.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6" id="ifYes1" style="text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Meine E-Mail Adresse</label>
    <div class="position-relative">
      <i class="far fa-paper-plane text-color-primary text-3 position-absolute left-10 top-50pct transform3dy-n50"></i>
      <input type="email" value="" placeholder="bl4cklistde@gmail.com" maxlength="100" class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="email" required style="padding:35px;">
      <div class="help-tip" style="top:-30px;left:175px;">
        <p>Trage hier deine E-Mail ein, damit wir dir antworten können.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6" id="ifYes2" style="text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Überschrift</label>
    <div class="position-relative">
      <i class="far fa-edit text-color-primary text-3 position-absolute left-10 top-50pct transform3dy-n50"></i>
      <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Frage zu eurem Support-Bot" maxlength="50" class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="subject" required style="padding:35px;">
      <div class="help-tip" style="top:-30px;left:93px;">
        <p>Erkläre hier kurzgefasst worum es bei deinem Anliegen geht.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6" id="ifYes3" style="text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Thema deiner Frage</label>
    <div class="custom-select-1">
      <select class="form-control text-3 h-auto" name="city" maxlength="100" required>
        <option value="">Thema auswählen..</option>
        <option value="Webseite">Unsere Webseite</option>
        <option value="Discord-Bots">Unsere Discord-Bots</option>
        <option value="Discord-Server">Unser Discord-Server</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row" id="ifYes4" style="">
  <div class="form-group col">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Erkläre nun dein Anliegen..</label>
    <div class="position-relative">
      <i class="far fa-comment-dots text-color-primary text-3 position-absolute left-10 top-50pct transform3dy-n50"></i>
      <textarea maxlength="2000" rows="5" placeholder="Verfasse eine Nachricht.." class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="message" required style="padding:35px;"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row" id="ifYes5" style="">
  <div class="form-group col">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="finish1" value="Meine Frage abschicken" class="btn btn-primary btn-modern" data-loading-text="Laden..">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- User-Report -->

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col" id="ifYes6" style="text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Mein Discord-Name
                                    <div class="help-tip" style="left:105px;"><p>Trage ihn ein, damit wir dich persönlich ansprechen können.</p></div>
                                </label>
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Max Mustermann" maxlength="100" class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="name" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col" id="ifYes7" style="text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Meine E-Mail Adresse
                                    <div class="help-tip" style="left:180px;"><p>Trage hier deine E-Mail ein, damit wir dir antworten können.</p></div>
                                </label>
    <input type="email" value="" placeholder="bl4cklistde@gmail.com" maxlength="100" class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="email" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col" id="ifYes8" style="text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Überschrift
                                    <div class="help-tip" style="left:105px;"><p>Erkläre hier kurzgefasst worum es bei deinem Anliegen geht.</p></div>
                                </label>
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Frage zu eurem Support-Bot" maxlength="50" class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="subject" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col" id="ifYes9" style="text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Thema deiner Frage</label>
    <div class="custom-select-1">
      <select class="form-control h-auto" name="city" maxlength="100" required>
        <option value="">Thema auswählen..</option>
        <option value="Webseite">Unsere Webseite</option>
        <option value="Discord-Bots">Unsere Discord-Bots</option>
        <option value="Discord-Server">Unser Discord-Server</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row" id="ifYes10" style="">
  <div class="form-group col">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Erkläre nun dein Anliegen..</label>
    <textarea maxlength="2000" rows="5" class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="message" required></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row" id="ifYes11" style="">
  <div class="form-group col">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="finish1" value="Meine Frage abschicken" class="btn btn-primary btn-modern" data-loading-text="Laden..">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Btw, you forgot to add the smooth scrolling to the javascript code.

Comment: Well, you didn't provide the `<p id="formstart">` in your question code but I grabbed it now from your page and put it into my answer for completeness. ;-)

Comment: Small another question, how can i create a website redirect to the "Entbannungs-Antrag" option?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your logic.

When the user chooses the `yesCheck` option, you display all those DIVs. But then you also execute the `else` blocks for `yesCheck1` and `noCheck`, which undoes some of its changes.

Since all the options are mutually exclusive, you should use `else if` to step through each choice, with a final `else` for the remaining choice.

```js
function yesnoCheck() {

  // Allgemeine Fragen

  if (document.getElementById("yesCheck").selected) {
    document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes2").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes3").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes4").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes5").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("formstart").scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  }

  // User-Report
  else if (document.getElementById("yesCheck1").selected) {
    document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes3").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes4").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes5").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes6").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes7").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes8").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes9").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes10").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes11").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("formstart").scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  }

  // No Check
  else if (document.getElementById("noCheck").selected) {
    document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes3").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes4").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifYes5").style.display = "none";
  }

  // Entsperrungs Antrag
  else {
    document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes2").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes3").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes4").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ifYes5").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col">
    <label class="mb-1 text-6"><img class="rounded" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/2222/2222355.png" height="30" width="30"> - Wie können wir dir helfen?</label>
    <div class="custom-select-1">

      <!-- Here is the JavaScript function started -->

      <select onchange="yesnoCheck(this);" class="form-control h-auto" name="city" required>
        <option id="noCheck" value="">Thema auswählen..</option>
        <option id="yesCheck" value="Allgemeine-Frage"> - Allgemeine Frage zu Bl4cklist</option>
        <option id="yesCheck1" value="User-Report"> - Server-Mitglied verstößt gegen Regeln</option>
        <option id="yesCheck2" value="Entsperrungs-Antrag"> - Mein Account wurde vom Server gesperrt</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Allgemeine-Frage -->

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6" id="ifYes" style="display: none;text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Mein Name</label>
    <div class="position-relative">
      <i class="far fa-user-circle text-color-primary text-3 position-absolute left-10 top-50pct transform3dy-n50"></i>
      <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Max Mustermann" maxlength="100" class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="name" required style="padding:35px;">
      <div class="help-tip" style="top:-30px;left:97px;">
        <p>Trage ihn ein, damit wir dich persönlich ansprechen können.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6" id="ifYes1" style="display: none;text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Meine E-Mail Adresse</label>
    <div class="position-relative">
      <i class="far fa-paper-plane text-color-primary text-3 position-absolute left-10 top-50pct transform3dy-n50"></i>
      <input type="email" value="" placeholder="bl4cklistde@gmail.com" maxlength="100" class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="email" required style="padding:35px;">
      <div class="help-tip" style="top:-30px;left:175px;">
        <p>Trage hier deine E-Mail ein, damit wir dir antworten können.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6" id="ifYes2" style="display: none;text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Überschrift</label>
    <div class="position-relative">
      <i class="far fa-edit text-color-primary text-3 position-absolute left-10 top-50pct transform3dy-n50"></i>
      <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Frage zu eurem Support-Bot" maxlength="50" class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="subject" required style="padding:35px;">
      <div class="help-tip" style="top:-30px;left:93px;">
        <p>Erkläre hier kurzgefasst worum es bei deinem Anliegen geht.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6" id="ifYes3" style="display: none;text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Thema deiner Frage</label>
    <div class="custom-select-1">
      <select class="form-control text-3 h-auto" name="city" maxlength="100" required>
        <option value="">Thema auswählen..</option>
        <option value="Webseite">Unsere Webseite</option>
        <option value="Discord-Bots">Unsere Discord-Bots</option>
        <option value="Discord-Server">Unser Discord-Server</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row" id="ifYes4" style="display: none;">
  <div class="form-group col">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Erkläre nun dein Anliegen..</label>
    <div class="position-relative">
      <i class="far fa-comment-dots text-color-primary text-3 position-absolute left-10 top-50pct transform3dy-n50"></i>
      <textarea maxlength="2000" rows="5" placeholder="Verfasse eine Nachricht.." class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="message" required style="padding:35px;"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row" id="ifYes5" style="display: none;">
  <div class="form-group col">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="finish1" value="Meine Frage abschicken" class="btn btn-primary btn-modern" data-loading-text="Laden..">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- User-Report -->

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col" id="ifYes6" style="display: none;text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Mein Discord-Name
                                    <div class="help-tip" style="left:105px;"><p>Trage ihn ein, damit wir dich persönlich ansprechen können.</p></div>
                                </label>
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Max Mustermann" maxlength="100" class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="name" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col" id="ifYes7" style="display: none;text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Meine E-Mail Adresse
                                    <div class="help-tip" style="left:180px;"><p>Trage hier deine E-Mail ein, damit wir dir antworten können.</p></div>
                                </label>
    <input type="email" value="" placeholder="bl4cklistde@gmail.com" maxlength="100" class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="email" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col" id="ifYes8" style="display: none;text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Überschrift
                                    <div class="help-tip" style="left:105px;"><p>Erkläre hier kurzgefasst worum es bei deinem Anliegen geht.</p></div>
                                </label>
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Frage zu eurem Support-Bot" maxlength="50" class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="subject" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col" id="ifYes9" style="display: none;text-align: left;">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Thema deiner Frage</label>
    <div class="custom-select-1">
      <select class="form-control h-auto" name="city" maxlength="100" required>
        <option value="">Thema auswählen..</option>
        <option value="Webseite">Unsere Webseite</option>
        <option value="Discord-Bots">Unsere Discord-Bots</option>
        <option value="Discord-Server">Unser Discord-Server</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row" id="ifYes10" style="display: none;">
  <div class="form-group col">
    <label class="mb-1 text-4">Erkläre nun dein Anliegen..</label>
    <textarea maxlength="2000" rows="5" class="form-control text-3 h-auto py-2" name="message" required></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row" id="ifYes11" style="display: none;">
  <div class="form-group col">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="finish1" value="Meine Frage abschicken" class="btn btn-primary btn-modern" data-loading-text="Laden..">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yesCheck1 (User-Report) is now always displayed if i switch from "Thema auswählen.." to "Allgemeine-Frage" and than back to "Thema auswählen".

Comment: I don't know which DIVs are supposed to be shown in each case, I just copied those from your code. You're not updating the style of each one in all blocks. Fix those to do what you want.